# How do i switch between different users(github accounts) when pushing repositories?

Tags: git, github

Here is the problem I run into.

First of all, I'm working on several different projects.
I've got two different github accounts, and after setting up one of them and successfully pushing a repo to it, I needed to commit/push the other repo to the second account which got me to the exact problem.

How do I switch between these two accounts using https way and not ssh?

P.S: I'm on Mac.

I've tried to change git config global/local user names and emails, but it didn't work out. I keep getting the same error which is:

> " remote: Permission to name/repo.git denied to User.
>   fatal: unable to access 'repos address' : The requested URL returned error: 403".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to use different ssh keys.

Read this full documents and follow the steps.

### Multiple SSH Keys settings for different github account:

https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

---

### ***`create different public key`***

create different ssh key according the article Mac Set-Up Git

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"
```

for example, 2 keys created at:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa_activehacker
~/.ssh/id_rsa_jexchan
```

### ***`Add these two keys to the ssh-agent:`***

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_activehacker
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_jexchan
you can delete all cached keys before

$ ssh-add -D
```

### ***`check your keys`***

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

### ***`Modify the ssh config`***

```
$ cd ~/.ssh/
$ touch config
$ subl -a config
```

#### `Add the keys to the config file:`***

```
#activehacker account
Host github.com-activehacker
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_activehacker

#jexchan account
Host github.com-jexchan
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_jexchan
```

### ***`Clone you repo and modify your Git config`***

```
# clone your repo 
git clone git@github.com:activehacker/gfs.git gfs_jexchan

cd gfs_jexchan and modify git config

$ git config user.name "jexchan"
$ git config user.email "jexchan@gmail.com" 

$ git config user.name "activehacker"
$ git config user.email "jexlab@gmail.com" 

# or you can have global 
git config $ git config --global user.name "jexchan" 
git config --global user.email "jexchan@gmail.com"
```

### ***`push your code`***

```
# add the code and commit it
git add .
git commit -m "your comments"

# push the code to the remote server
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to add the ssh keys to respective accounts as well, else authentication will fail.

This one works flawlessly - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574